# Edit the source of a pdf file and it corrupts the pdf (could not be opened)

Tags: itext, pdf-generation, pdfstamper, pdf-rendering, pdfobject

Open up a PDF file from a text editor, I would like to modify the content of this object below:

`759 0 obj
($Revision::    1.0     $)
endobj
774 0 obj`

from 
`($Revision::    1.0     $)` to `($Revision::20171219200322$)`, i.e. the total size of the object increased by 2 characters.

However, this change breaks the PDF.

How does that happen? I'm guessing there is somewhere else in the PDF that relies on the size of the obj.

could someone shed some light on it?

Much appreciated

===================UPDATE==================

Thanks for the comments below.

I tried to look for the xref table throughout the pdf file, but only found something like this:

`...
endobj
startxref
116666
%%EOF`

at the bottom of the file. There's no actual table there. Any idea?

Thanks for the help.

===================UPDATE 22/12/2017 ==================

Now I was able to find the AcroFields that's need to be modified using iText. 
However, I don't want to use `AcroFields.setField(String name, String value)` method to set the field value, I would like to modify the value of `PdfString` object that this field is referring to. I was able to get the object by calling `PdfReader.getPdfObject(item.getMerged(0).get(PdfName.DV))` which gives me a PdfString Object, but I couldn't find a way to change the value of it. Any idea?

Comment: At the end of the document you'll probably find a xref table; in there are the offsets of the numbered objects in the PDF. By increasing the size of the String above you rendered all the entries for later objects in that table incorrect. Furthermore, editing a PDF in a text editor is quite likely to damage the PDF. PDFs are binary data (even though some structures are text-like), so not what text editors are meant to edit (some editors here are less destructive than others).

Comment: This question was tagged `itext` but it is not about iText. Why?

Comment: A PDF is a binary file that consists of objects with specific byte offsets. The chance that you can change the content of a binary file without corrupting the file is small.

Comment: Concerning your update: ah, so your pdf makes use of the option to use a cross reference stream instead of a cross reference table. In that case the cross reference data are in a stream object at file offset 116666 (or wherever your edit has moved that object); this is quite unfortunate for you as such streams usually are compressed, so you cannot simply edit them without further ado. I would recommend using a programmatic approach. As you tagged your question [tag:itext]: you can use iText for that task.

Comment: what does your newest update have to do with the question as it was?